# How to get the square of elements in list of lists using map?

Tags: python, list

Consider the following list of lists:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]]
```

I want to get the square of it, using `map` with a `lambda` function. The result should be:

```
arr = [[1, 4, 9], [9, 4, 1]]
```

I tried this:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: [lst**2 for lsts in arr for lst in lsts], arr)))
```

But I get that as answer:

```
[[1, 4, 9, 9, 4, 1], [1, 4, 9, 9, 4, 1]]
```

Comment: The `map` already gives you one level of iteration over `arr`. Just change the `lambda` to iterate the inner level: `lambda x: [num**2 for num in x]`...

Comment: You could also modify the contents of your current `lambda` to be a stand-alone comprehension: `print([[num**2 for num in lst] for lst in arr])`, no need of `map`

Comment: oh ok so a comprehension inside a comprehension will iterate in the list of lists and give back the same structure as a result ? interesting

Comment: You could also use `map` twice: `arr = list(map(lambda sub: list(map(lambda x: x**2, sub)), arr))`

Comment: map twice doesn't look too clean, nested comprehension or map+comprehension is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Sure, was just trying to show that are many ways to get to the same. In my opinion the nested list-comp here is the best option

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr = list(map(lambda List: [x**2 for x in List], arr))
# Output : [[1, 4, 9], [9, 4, 1]]
```

You can also use nested mapping:

```
arr = list(map(lambda List: list(map(lambda x: x**2, List)), arr))
# or
square = lambda x: x**2
arr = list(map(lambda List: list(map(square, List)), arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works combining both `lambda`s and list-comprehension:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

print(list(map(lambda x: [i * i for i in x], arr)))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4, 9], [16, 25, 36]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
output = list(map(lambda x: [i**2 for i in x], arr))
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using numpy:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]

arr_numpy = np.array(arr)

result = arr_numpy ** 2
```

Comment: I'm aware of numpy, I want map but thanks

Comment: @w_sz learned something new here, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you want to use `map` and `lambda` but for reference, you can do this just using list comprehensions,

```
[[y * y for y in x] for x in arr]
```